# what is this warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I created the 3 layouts HDPI and MDPI and LDPI and I edit the any one of xml file, in console, they show the error:

> warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is a common warning  when including jar files.

Use below line in proguard to avoid warning

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: It actually doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Maybe this works for release APK, but what about debug builds?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky debug builds don't run ProGuard (unless you enable yourself) and I think it happens when ProGuard runs.

Comment: @Sufian Then how to get rid of this error in Android Studio??

Comment: To the above comment, I've replied [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963947/fix-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-warning#comment69248674_37963947). Referencing so that someone who has the same question knows what to do. :)