# Fix “Ignoring InnerClasses attribute” warning

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, compilation

I would like to fix this warning that give me each build this output:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$6) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$7) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Structure$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

I have already tried the other solution given on these questions:

- [what is this warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141832/what-is-this-warning-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-for-an-anonymous-inner-cla)
- [What is the “Ignoring InnerClasses attribute” warning output during compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-warning-output-during-compilation/3308059#3308059)
- [Progaurd issue “Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796144/progaurd-issue-warningignoring-innerclasses-attribute-for-an-anonymous-inner-c)
- [android Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class jar file issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993474/android-dx-warning-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-for-an-anonymous-inner-class)

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.marco.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
        incremental true
        dexInProcess = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar')

    //include jar libraries -> rstincanoffline dependencies
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/tincan-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-jarjar.jar')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    // stetho -> for debug purpose
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.3.1'

    //gson dependency
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    //google autovalue dependencies
    //apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    apt 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    apt 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2'
    apt 'com.sun.jna:jna:3.0.9'

    //picasso dependency
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //realm dependency
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.83.0+'
}
```

If someone could help me that would be great!

Comment: Did this happen on release or debug?

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing a similar situation in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes me too, its happening on every build of the project in debug mode.

Comment: @Yogesh did you try following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141832/what-is-this-warning-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-for-an-anonymous-inner-cla)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky did you try following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141832/what-is-this-warning-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-for-an-anonymous-inner-cla). Also please make sure that you're putting it in the correct proguard rules file.

Comment: I think Mark, you're putting the `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` inside the wrong ProGuard rules file. But it is also weird that you've disabled ProGuard (`minifyEnabled false`) and you're getting this message.

Comment: @Sufian That answer is not relevant for debug builds (where this error is occurring in Android Studio).

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky does it happen in debug or release? Do you have `minifyEnabled true` enabled in your gradle? If so, can you share the block inside which it is written?

Comment: @Sufian Nothing of the sort in gradle debug.  In fact, this is probably happening for me because of Adobe AIR library I am using in my project.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky if that library is added as a module, try this: in **Build Variants** (at the left side of AS, you may need to click that square/monitor at bottom left of your IDE) change the dropdown next to your library to "debug". It must be in release and causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by changing this line in my proguard file:

```
-keepattributes Signature,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

to the following:

```
-keepattributes Signature,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod
```